# Blazor Emit Javascript to Close Browser Window

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to close the browser window from a Blazor Server page. In asp.net I would do the following:

```
       Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>")
```

How would I do this on a Blazor Server page?

Thanks

Comment: Please read about [JS interop in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy

```
@inject IJSRuntime js


@code
{

public void CloseWindow(){

   js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.close");
}

}
```

Comment: How would I call this in the code-behind .cs file?

Comment: using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace Vir.Pages
{
    public partial class VirapiComponent
    {
        [Inject] IJSRuntime js;                                                                                                          I get "Inject" not valid.......

Comment: Disregard... I was able to get it to work in the .cs file. Thanks!